# SET ROLE xxx command extremely slow

Tags: postgresql, role, postgresql-9.5

On Amazon RDS, I setup a Postgresql database. I have a custom user table, each user in my database maps to a specific role. The role are created via a trigger and I keep the role in the same custom user table for future reference.

I made a mistake on the role, and had to remove them all, and recreate them with new properties (about 60k roles). I assume there might be a VACUUM problem but I cannot control the VACUUM of the system tables in AWS RDS.

The issue is now that I set a role, for example: SET ROLE app_role_custom;
It takes more than 30 seconds!!

After my first connection I get the following debug messages, and upon setting my roles I get:

```
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 17 tups, 8 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 33 tups, 16 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 65 tups, 32 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 129 tups, 64 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 257 tups, 128 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 513 tups, 256 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 1025 tups, 512 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 2049 tups, 1024 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 4097 tups, 2048 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 8193 tups, 4096 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 16385 tups, 8192 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 32769 tups, 16384 buckets
DEBUG:  rehashing catalog cache id 8 for pg_auth_members; 65537 tups, 32768 buckets
SET
```

Then if I do "SET ROLE none" and then set the same role again I get:

```
====> Up to this point is quite fast, then
====> This takes way more than 30 seconds to execute and display the following message:
SET
```

I also ran a query, whose giving me bloat ratio

```
 current_database |     schemaname     |         tblname         | real_size  |  extra_size   |    extra_ratio    | fillfactor | bloat_size |    bloat_ratio    | is_na 
------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+-------------------+-------
 demo      | information_schema | sql_features            | 0 bytes    | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | information_schema | sql_implementation_info | 0 bytes    | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | information_schema | sql_languages           | 0 bytes    | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | information_schema | sql_packages            | 0 bytes    | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | information_schema | sql_sizing              | 0 bytes    | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | internal           | answers                 | 2160 kB    | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | internal           | comments                | 20 MB      | 376 kB        |  1.83881064162754 |        100 |     385024 |  1.83881064162754 | f
 demo      | internal           | posts                   | 54 MB      | 832 kB        |  1.49554213402358 |        100 |     851968 |  1.49554213402358 | f
 demo      | internal           | questions               | 6496 kB    | 160 kB        |  2.46305418719212 |        100 |     163840 |  2.46305418719212 | f
 demo      | internal           | users                   | 4112 kB    | -155648 bytes |                 0 |        100 |    -155648 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_aggregate            | 16 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_am                   | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_amop                 | 48 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_amproc               | 32 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_attribute            | 384 kB     | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_auth_members         | 5536 kB    | 24 kB         | 0.433526011560694 |        100 |      24576 | 0.433526011560694 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_cast                 | 16 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_class                | 72 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_collation            | 224 kB     | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_constraint           | 8192 bytes | -8192 bytes   |                 0 |        100 |      -8192 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_conversion           | 24 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_database             | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_depend               | 448 kB     | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_description          | 264 kB     | 8192 bytes    |  3.03030303030303 |        100 |       8192 |  3.03030303030303 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_extension            | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_index                | 24 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_language             | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_namespace            | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_opclass              | 24 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_operator             | 120 kB     | 8192 bytes    |  6.66666666666667 |        100 |       8192 |  6.66666666666667 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_opfamily             | 16 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_pltemplate           | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_proc                 | 584 kB     | 8192 bytes    |  1.36986301369863 |        100 |       8192 |  1.36986301369863 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_range                | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_rewrite              | 96 kB      | 8192 bytes    |  8.33333333333333 |        100 |       8192 |  8.33333333333333 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_shdepend             | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_shdescription        | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_tablespace           | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_trigger              | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_ts_config            | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_ts_config_map        | 16 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_ts_dict              | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_ts_parser            | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_ts_template          | 8192 bytes | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
 demo      | pg_catalog         | pg_type                 | 72 kB      | 0 bytes       |                 0 |        100 |          0 |                 0 | t
```

And same for indexes, it seems the pg_auth_members indexes are affected:

```
current_database | schemaname  |     tblname      |              idxname              | real_size | extra_size |    extra_ratio    | fillfactor | bloat_size |    bloat_ratio    | is_na 
------------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+------------+------------+-------------------+-------
 demo      | internal    | answers          | answers_pkey                      |    966656 |      98304 |  10.1694915254237 |         90 |       8192 | 0.847457627118644 | f
 demo      | internal    | comments         | comments_pkey                     |   2187264 |     229376 |  10.4868913857678 |         90 |       8192 | 0.374531835205993 | f
 demo      | internal    | posts            | posts_pkey                        |   1622016 |     163840 |  10.1010101010101 |         90 |       8192 | 0.505050505050505 | f
 demo      | internal    | questions        | questions_pkey                    |    679936 |      73728 |  10.8433734939759 |         90 |       8192 |  1.20481927710843 | f
 demo      | internal    | users            | users_pkey                        |   1449984 |     147456 |  10.1694915254237 |         90 |       8192 | 0.564971751412429 | f
 demo      | manati_auth | users            | users_pkey                        |   1449984 |     147456 |  10.1694915254237 |         90 |       8192 | 0.564971751412429 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_aggregate     | pg_aggregate_fnoid_index          |     16384 |          0 |                 0 |         90 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_am            | pg_am_name_index                  |     16384 |          0 |                 0 |         90 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_amop          | pg_amop_fam_strat_index           |     40960 |       8192 |                20 |         90 |       8192 |                20 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_amop          | pg_amop_opr_fam_index             |     40960 |       8192 |                20 |         90 |       8192 |                20 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_amproc        | pg_amproc_fam_proc_index          |     40960 |      16384 |                40 |         90 |       8192 |                20 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_attribute     | pg_attribute_relid_attnam_index   |    139264 |     -90112 | -64.7058823529412 |         90 |    -114688 | -82.3529411764706 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_attribute     | pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index   |     98304 |      32768 |  33.3333333333333 |         90 |      24576 |                25 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_auth_members  | pg_auth_members_member_role_index |   4841472 |    2252800 |  46.5313028764805 |         90 |    1966080 |  40.6091370558376 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_auth_members  | pg_auth_members_role_member_index |   4177920 |    1589248 |  38.0392156862745 |         90 |    1302528 |  31.1764705882353 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_cast          | pg_cast_source_target_index       |     16384 |          0 |                 0 |         90 |          0 |                 0 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_class         | pg_class_relname_nsp_index        |     57344 |      16384 |  28.5714285714286 |         90 |      16384 |  28.5714285714286 | f
 demo      | pg_catalog  | pg_class         | pg_class_tblspc_relfilenode_index |     40960 |      24576 |                60 |         90 |      24576 |                60 | f
```

Comment: Can you show the results of this query to see whether you are suffering catalog bloat: `SELECT relname, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) FROM pg_class C LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace) WHERE nspname = 'pg_catalog' ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 10;`

Comment: pg_rewrite                        | 96 kB
    pg_transform_oid_index            | 8192 bytes
    pg_inherits_relid_seqno_index     | 8192 bytes
    pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index | 8192 bytes
    pg_enum_typid_sortorder_index     | 8192 bytes
    pg_largeobject_loid_pn_index      | 8192 bytes
    pg_inherits_parent_index          | 8192 bytes
    pg_enum_typid_label_index         | 8192 bytes
    pg_enum_oid_index                 | 8192 bytes
    pg_event_trigger_evtname_index    | 8192 bytes

Comment: @JoshKupershmidt Tell me if you need me to reformat that answer

Comment: Is that index bloat ?

Comment: I don't think so, all your tables look tiny, it must be some other issue.

Comment: But the bloat ratio for pg_auth_members_member_role_index and pg_auth_members_role_member_index seems pretty high.